# Error when trying to do a bank withdraw simulator in Python

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and i'm trying to make a program that withdraws money from a bank according to user input. The only works with $100, $50 and $20 bills.
If i type in 60, 80, 110 and other values the program goes for the highest bill available, and the withdraw money that is left the bank can't withdraw it...

Here's the code:

```
 while True:
    try:
        money_amount = int(input('How much you want to withdraw? '))
        if money_amount == 0:
            print('Type in a valid value.')
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('Not accepted. Try again.')
    else:
        print(f'Withdraw amount: $ {money_amount:.2f}')
        for bill_value in [100, 50, 20]:
            bill_quantity = money_amount // bill_value  # Divide saque // valor p/ encontrar quantia de cédulas
            money_amount %= bill_value  # Pega o resto da divisão de saque / valor. O que sobrar é calculado no próximo loop
            print(f'$ {bill_value} Bills → {bill_quantity}')

        if money_amount != 0:
            print(f'\033[31mERROR!\033[m This bank uses only \033[33m $ 100, $ 50 and $ 20 bills!!!\033[m')
            print('Try again.')
            continue
        break
print('\033[32mOperation Success\033[m')
```

If i add the value $ 1 to the Item list, the operation never fails...
[100, 50, 20, 1] - It works, but that's not a fix...
I would be grateful if someone could help me understand why this happens and what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Not all numbers are evenly divisible by 100, 50, and 20. For example if you input 14 there is no way to pay that with the denominations listed. It always works when you include a one dollar bill because all numbers are divisible by one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to do it without needing to have 1 in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your withdraw logic has a fundamental flaw - you go from biggest to lowest denomiation. That does not work with the limited bills you allow.

You can only change money that

- by itself divides by 20 without remainder
- or when subtracted 50 (and not going negative) divides by 20 without remainder
- 100 is just a fancy way to deal 5 twenties

any other input can not be changed. You can code accordingly:

```
def canBeChanged(x):
    return (x/20.0 == x//20.0) or x>=50 and ((x-50)/20.0 == (x-50)//20.0)


money = [1000, 110, 80, 60, 50, 20, 73, 10]

for m in money: 
    tmp = m
    if canBeChanged(m):
        change = []
        isDiv20 = (tmp/20.0 == tmp//20.0)  # divides by 20 without remainder
        if not isDiv20:
            change.append(50)              # remove 50, now it divides
            tmp -= 50

        twenties = tmp // 20       # how many 20's left?
        while twenties >=5:        # how many 100 bills can we combine from 5 20's?
            change.append(100)
            twenties -= 5
        while twenties:            # how many 20's left?
            change.append(20)
            twenties -= 1

        print(m, " == ", sorted(change))
    else:
        print(m, "can not be changed")
```

Output:

```
1000  ==  [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
110  ==  [20, 20, 20, 50]
80  ==  [20, 20, 20, 20]
60  ==  [20, 20, 20]
50  ==  [50]
20  ==  [20]
73 can not be changed
10 can not be changed
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood now... With your help i was able to fix my code

Comment: Your two conditions made me understand that i was doing it wrong. I did'nt do any of the conditions before ( Divisible by 20 ), did'nt tought about that. Thanks again